# Java, how to write or add instead of overwriting a textfile?

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedwriter

I wonder why my program overwrites existing text in the textfile instead of adding a new line of text?

```
public class WriteToFile {

    public void registerTrainingSession(Customer customer) {

        Path outFilePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Allan\\Documents\\Nackademin\\OOP\\Inlämningsuppgift2\\visits.txt");


        try (BufferedWriter save = Files.newBufferedWriter(outFilePath)) {

            String trainingSession = String.format("Member: %s %s\nPersonalnumber: %s\nTraining session date: %s\n", customer.getFirstName(),
                    customer.getLastName(), customer.getPersonalNumber(), LocalDate.now());


            save.write(trainingSession);
            save.flush();

        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer info is missing!");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be created.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code overwrites the file because you didn't specify an [`OpenOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/OpenOption.html) on the [`newBufferedWriter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) call.

As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) says:

> If no options are present then this method works as if the `CREATE`, `TRUNCATE_EXISTING`, and `WRITE` options are present. In other words, it opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or initially **truncating an existing `regular-file` to a size of `0`** if it exists.

Try:

```
 Files.newBufferedWriter(outFilePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                      StandardOpenOption.APPEND,
                                      StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
```

Or if the file must already exist, failing if it doesn't:

```
 Files.newBufferedWriter(outFilePath, StandardOpenOption.APPEND,
                                      StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
```

To write a new file, failing if it already exists

```
 Files.newBufferedWriter(outFilePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW,
                                      StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
```

Comment: thank you. We haven't been taught about StandardOpenOption yet. All this is very new to me.

Comment: @AllanJ You won't be taught every small detail of the Java API, it is simply way too huge for that. That is why you need to **learn to read the javadoc**, so you can go research which methods exists, and what choices you have for parameters.